# Dragging Files on the Dock Icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know how handle dragging of files on the dock icon, and it has been asked before.

However, I'm wondering, can I somehow get more control?

For example, can I make the dock icon reject files that are *not* in the user's folder and allow only files that are in the user's folder?

I'd rather do that instead of the app appearing as if it handles files outside the user's folder, and then within the app delegate afterwards reject the files by detecting the file paths. That doesn't seem good from a user's perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that my question is kind of meaningless, as Option-dropping files on the dock icons forces the operation to be allowed, in any case. So there is simply no getting around handling the thing after the drop operation has been allowed. Thus, ignore this question :)